# Compute agg fields ignoring duplicates using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

My MongoDB dataset consists of dates and temperatures. It shows some duplicate dates, for example:

```
{date: "01-01-1970", "tmed": 12.4}, 
{date: "01-02-1970", "tmed": 13.1},
{date: "01-02-1970", "tmed": 13.1}, 
{date: "01-03-1970", "tmed": 12.7}
```

We have a duplicate for "01-02-1970" with the same "tmed" value (Note: always, the "tmed" values are equal in a duplicate case).

I would like to compute the year average only considering one of the duplicates; otherwise, the average computed is just incorrect.

I am computing the general average as follows:

```
query_results = collection.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match": {'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(1973, 1, 1, 0, 0), '$lte': datetime.datetime(1973, 12, 31, 0, 0)}}},
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "year": {"$year": "$date"},
                },
                "avg": {"$avg": "$tmed"},
                "total": {"$sum": 1},
            }
        },
        {"$sort": {"_id.year": 1}},
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "year": "$_id.year",
                "avg_rounded": {"$round": ["$avg", 2]},
                "total": 1,
            }
        },
    ]
)
```

Which returns

```
[{'total': 369, 'year': 1973, 'avg_rounded': 16.15}]
```

What should I add change to accomplish the goal expressed below and get the average accounting only the 365 valid dates in a year?

Comment: One approach would be to do a separate $group (injected immediately after the $match) where the grouping `_id` field is the full `date` and use `$first` with `$$ROOT` to capture the rest of the document. How common are duplicates?